# Conversion to longitude/latitude

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, latitude-longitude, select-by-attribute

I am very new to GIS. I wanted to find out if it is possible to convert coordinates as specified in the table below to longitude and latitude c[image: the image stipulates the constituencies in Malawi and their coordinates]

Comment: I can't see any coordinates in that table - the names look like districts of Malawi though. Where has this spreadsheet come from? Maybe it does have some coordinate information with it? Please edit your question and let's see if we can fix this for you!

Comment: The *polygon* contains the coordinate data. Either you need to extract a centroid and add it to the attribute table or create a new CLOB field for the Well-Known Text and populate that.

Comment: Yes as @Vince says, you have to calculate the centroid of the polygon. You can do so by adding a Lat and Long column, right-click on the new column and use "calculate geometry". See: https://grindgis.com/software/how-to-calculate-the-centroid-of-a-polygon-in-arcgis for a better guide.